# Java MapReduce Counters - Oozie

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, oozie

Java applications are executed in the Hadoop cluster as map-reduce job with a single Mapper task. If a java mapreduce job(not hive or any other job just a direct mapreduce job) is a part of oozie we get a single mapper launcher and actual mapreduce job runs independently. So is there a way to link the launcher and the actual mapreduce job run? like get the jobid of the actual action running with launcher jobid? any command to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the launcher id for any child id from the **logs link** that can be obtained from

```
http://<rm httpaddress:port>/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/<jobid>/jobattempts
```

There we get an xml which contains the logs link. If we parse through the **syslog** in that link we have a string like

```
Service: job_
```

Use this regular expression and find out the launcher id. If there is a launcher then we can get it from here.(Even for java actions in oozie workflow)
The actual line will be something like this

```
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: <jobid>
```

The jobid after the `Service:` is launcher job id

Answer (score 1):

You can go the oozie UI and get this information. Click on the action which you want and go to `Child Job URLs` tab. There you can find all the child jobs launched by the particular action.

`java` action in oozie without child url:

[image]

`map-reduce` action in oozie with child urls tab:

[image]

For the map-rdeuce jobs, you can visit the `Child Job URLs` tab and get all the child mapreduce job urls.

Comment: yes is there any other way other than this? Thanks a lot for the above suggestion.Is there anything common in the independent jobid information  and the launcher information?

Comment: I am not aware of the command to find this. other possibility is using the oozie java api. What is the requirement and how frequent you do this?

Comment: i am not aware of oozie java api is it 8080/oozie url?

Comment: or is it 11000 port api?

Comment: Also the first solution that you gave like getting Child Job URLs works for actions that are mapreduce or hive or pig, but not for java-actions. The launcher job ids are noway linked to the external child ids in case of java-actions. The launcher job's logs on the job history server also do not have any job ids that can link us to its spawned child ids.

Comment: I have added the screen shots. Are you running mar-reduce jobs from a java action?

Comment: Yes, precisely. But we have a constraint that we cannot change our java actions to map reduce actions.

Comment: Not able to find anything at the moment. Let you know If I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The **ideal way** is to use the oozie client java api. The API would help you to get the workflow ID and then from that you could get the external id which is the actual hadoop job id.
Refer [this](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/client/apidocs/org/apache/oozie/client/OozieClient.html) and [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.oozie.client.WorkflowJob) .

**Alternate approach** is to use the oozie clients web services api. This returns a json for the entire job  details for a particular workflow. Then you could add a json parser to extract the externalID out of it to get the actual hadoop job id.
Refer [this](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Managing_a_Job) for the existing webservice urls.